# Why get I this error "module * already defined "?

Tags: cordova, ionic4, wallpaper

I'm trying to create a new project with this cordova library :

> https://github.com/fbsanches/cordova-plugin-wallpaper

However, i get this error when i'm building the app :

```
Uncaught module cordova-plugin-wallpaper.wallpaper already defined
```

Do you have some idea ?!

I build with this command :

```
ionic cordova run android --device -l --debug
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix this deleting from file `www/wallpaper.js` the first line:

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-wallpaper.wallpaper", function(require, exports, module) {
```

and last line:

```
});
```

And then remove and add the platform again.